# why %new sessions by month differs from averaging %new sessions by each day of that month

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have the following problem,
I want to see the percentage of new sessions in a given month. I am specifically interested in new sessions by "direct" channelgrouping

in custom report I set dimensions for November: yearMonth, source, medium, channelgrouping. and metrics:percentNewSessions 
it gives me 35%

then I create a custom reports with the same dimension but with Date as a metric.I average the %new session and get 38%

why does it differ? What should I trust?

Answer (score 1):

Both of these measures are true, but they tell something different.

Another simple use case with date metric:

```
Day 1: visitor A
Day 1: visitor B
...
Day 7: visitor A
Day 7: visitor C

— Week unique visitors: 3
— Week sum of daily unique visitors: 4
```

Define your KPI, what is measured, how it is measured, the period for measurement, and always stick with the KPI parameters; else you're on another one :)